# Parse through folders and sub folders to copy text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I am trying to copy all text files from a directory to another using a batch file. If in case the directory contains any sub folder the program must also parse the subfolder and copy the text file from folder and sub folder. If the files have the same name in the target folder(`dTarget`) rename the file before copying.
Following Is the code used

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "dSource=c:\test\a"
set "dTarget=c:\test\op"
set "fType=*.txt"

for %%i in ("%dSource%\%fType%") do if not exist "%dtarget%\%%~nxi" (copy /b "%%~i" "%dtarget%") else call :process "%%~i"

goto :eof

:process
set /a cnt=-1
:loop
set /a cnt+=1
set "fname=%dtarget%\%~n1(%cnt%)%~x1"
if exist "%fname%" goto :loop
copy /b "%~1" "%fname%"
goto :eof

endlocal
```

This program Works fine if there exist no subdirectory, I tried to use `/R` but of no use, only the directory files are copied. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "dSource=c:\test\a"
set "dTarget=c:\test\op"
set "fType=*.txt"

DIR /A:D /B %dSource%  > folders.txt

for /f %%G in (folders.txt) do for %%i in ("%dSource%\%%G\%fType%") do if not exist "%dtarget%\%%~nxi" (copy /b "%%~i" "%dtarget%") else call :process "%%~i"

goto :eof

:process
set /a cnt=-1
:loop
set /a cnt+=1
set "fname=%dtarget%\%~n1(%cnt%)%~x1"
if exist "%fname%" goto :loop
copy /b "%~1" "%fname%"
goto :eof

endlocal
```

Comment: Thank u :) This program only copies text file from subdirectories .... so I combined this program along with the program that I wrote :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another method which should succeed:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do copy /-Y "%%a" "d:\target\folder\%%~na - !random!!random!%%~xa"
```

Comment: since I want files only from `c:\test\a` I tried with `for /r %%a in (c:\test\a\*.txt)` but on doing this cmd prompt opens but no action is performed ....

Comment: Use this: `for /r "c:\test\a" %%a in (*.txt)`